# Is there a way to let template function automatically deduce an iterator's underlying data type?

Tags: c++, templates, c++11, iterator

I have a function where I need an iterator's underlying data type as return type, like this:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
#include <iterator>

template<class T, class ForwardIterator>
std::vector<T> get_odd(ForwardIterator data_begin, ForwardIterator data_end)
{
    std::vector<T> ret;
    std::copy_if(data_begin, data_end, std::back_inserter(ret), [](int x) { return x % 2; });
    return ret;
}

int main()
{
    std::vector<int> vi { 1, 2, 3, 4, 5 };
    for (auto i : get_odd<int>(vi.begin(), vi.end()))
        std::cout << i << ", ";
    std::cout << std::endl;

    std::vector<unsigned int> vui{ 9UL, 8UL, 7UL, 6UL, 5UL };
    // Note the 'char' I provided to the function, this will print weird chars
    for (auto i : get_odd<char>(vui.begin(), vui.end()))
        std::cout << i << ", ";
    std::cout << std::endl;

    return 0;
}
```

In the main(), I have to explicitly provide data type 'int' or 'char' to the get_odd function, is there a way to find out iterator's underlying data type, and let template automatically deduct the correct data type?

Comment: FYI, `get_odd` does not require a forward iterator, an input iterator will do just fine.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Iterator properties can be queried using [`std::iterator_traits`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/iterator/iterator_traits):

```
template<class ForwardIterator>
std::vector<typename std::iterator_traits<ForwardIterator>::value_type> 
get_odd(ForwardIterator data_begin, ForwardIterator data_end)
{
    std::vector<typename std::iterator_traits<ForwardIterator>::value_type> ret;
    std::copy_if(data_begin, data_end, std::back_inserter(ret), [](int x) { return x % 2; });
    return ret;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

If your compiler supports C++11, you can use:

```
#include <type_traits>
// ...
typename std::remove_reference<decltype(*data_begin)>::type
```

And probably `typedef` for convenience:

```
typedef typename std::remove_reference<decltype(*data_begin)>::type ContainedType;
std::vector<ContainedType> ret;
```

Comment: but how can I put std::remove_reference<decltype(*data_begin)>::type into the funtion's return type?

Comment: @dguan Use a trailing return type

Comment: @Angew My compiler rejects the code the way you edited it... ("typename cannot be used outside a template declaration")

Comment: @dguan See [this](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/C%2B%2B11#Alternative_function_syntax) for info on trailing return types. The downside is that you wouldn't be able to use the `typedef` there, so you'd have to repeat the entire remove_reference etc. expression.

Comment: @dlf the `template` is supposed to be started in the `...` portion

Comment: @dlf Then obviously you're using it someplace outside a tempalte. Unlike the OP, who works inside a function template.

Comment: @Angew. Got it (it seems odd that the requirement is based on whether the line happens to fall within a template or not, but after re-checking the purpose of the keyword, it makes sense). VC++ is really forgiving (too forgiving) about the use of `typename`, so I have never been entirely clear on exactly what the rules are.

Comment: @dlf There's a [detailed canonical question about `typename` and `template`](http://stackoverflow.com/q/610245/1782465) here on SO.

Comment: @dlf If what follows is a dependent type (a type that depends on a template parameter), you need to disambiguate it.  It could be a value or a type, if you did not clear the dependency, and the C++ langauge does not require that dependency to be cleared until the template is instantiated, but it does require you to know if it is a type or a value before that point.

Comment: @40two Neither will the `copy_if`, which requires at least input iterators. Also note that the OP's function suggests they are at least forward iterators.

Answer (score 2):

This comes up often enough that I use a convenient template alias to wrap `iterator_traits`:

```
template <typename I>
using ValueType = typename std::iterator_traits<I>::value_type;

template<class ForwardIterator>
std::vector<ValueType<ForwardIterator>>
get_odd(ForwardIterator data_begin, ForwardIterator data_end)
{
    std::vector<ValueType<ForwardIterator>> ret;
    std::copy_if(data_begin, data_end, std::back_inserter(ret), [](int x) {
        return x % 2;
    });
    return ret;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Use [std::iterator_traits](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/iterator/iterator_traits/):

```
template<class ForwardIterator>
std::vector<typename std::iterator_traits<ForwardIterator>::value_type> get_odd(ForwardIterator data_begin, ForwardIterator data_end)
{
    ....
}
```